# Q.js Q.all() when the length of array of promise is not sure

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to return an array of promise using Q.all(); 
like this:

```
return Q.all([
              list[0].getCssValue('height'),
              list[1].getCssValue('height'),
              ...,
              list[list.length-1]
              .getCssValue('height')
             ]);
```

I need to return all list in the array and I can get the length by array.length.

The question is that I can't

```
   for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
```

to make the return items like

```
list[i].getCssValue('height');
```

So how should I do this?

Comment: Notice that `Q.all` will give a promise for an array, not an array of promises.

Comment: Do your `getCssValue` function return a promise for a single value? Can you post its code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you actually *can* do it by creating a new array:

```
var arr = []
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    arr.push(list[i].getCssValue('height');
}
return Q.all(arr); // wait for all getCssValue actions
```

However, there is a more elegant way with `.map` that maps each element from an array to another:

```
return Q.all(arr.map(function(x){ return x.getCssValue('height'); });
```